# how to save DOMPDF generated content to file?

Tags: php, file, pdf-generation, save, dompdf

I am using Dompdf to create PDF file but I don't know why it doesn't save the created PDF to server.

Any ideas?

```
require_once("./pdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $html =
      '<html><body>'.
      '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
      'templating system.</p>'.
      '</body></html>';

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    file_put_contents('Brochure.pdf', $dompdf->output());
```

Comment: Version of dompdf? Any PHP errors?

Comment: dompdf 0.5.2, php 5.2.13

Comment: I don't see anything that would prevent you from saving, so I'm guessing a server configuration error. Perhaps PHP is unable to write to that directory? If that's the case PHP will report an error. Check your PHP error log or enable error display.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I have just used dompdf and the code was a little different but it worked.

Here it is:

```
require_once("./pdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$files = glob("./pdf/include/*.php");
foreach($files as $file) include_once($file);

$html =
      '<html><body>'.
      '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
      'templating system.</p>'.
      '</body></html>';

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents('Brochure.pdf', $output);
```

Only difference here is that all of the files in the include directory are included.

Other than that my only suggestion would be to specify a full directory path for writing the file rather than just the filename.

Answer (score 2):

I did test your code and the only problem I could see was the lack of permission given to the directory you try to write the file in to.

Give "write" permission to the directory you need to put the file. In your case it is the current directory.

Use "chmod" in linux.

Add "Everyone" with "write" enabled to the security tab of the directory if you are in Windows.

Answer (score -5):

```
<?php
$content='<table width="100%" border="1">';
$content.='<tr><th>name</th><th>email</th><th>contact</th><th>address</th><th>city</th><th>country</th><th>postcode</th></tr>';
for ($index = 0; $index < 10; $index++) { 
$content.='<tr><td>nadim</td><td>nadim.sheikh.07@gmail.com</td><td>7737033665</td><td>247 dehligate</td><td>udaipur</td><td>india</td><td>313001</td></tr>';
}
$content.='</table>';
//$html = file_get_contents('pdf.php');
if(isset($_POST['pdf'])){
    require_once('./dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF;                        
    $dompdf->load_html($content);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("hello.pdf");
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">        
            <button name="pdf" type="submit">export</button>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
           <tr><th>name</th><th>email</th><th>contact</th><th>address</th><th>city</th><th>country</th><th>postcode</th></tr>         
            <?php for ($index = 0; $index < 10; $index++) { ?>
            <tr><td>nadim</td><td>nadim.sheikh.07@gmail.com</td><td>7737033665</td><td>247 dehligate</td><td>udaipur</td><td>india</td><td>313001</td></tr>
            <?php } ?>            
        </table>        
        </form>        
    </body>
</html>
```