# How do I attach a generated pdf by dompdf into mail using sendgrid mail api?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, sendgrid, dompdf

I'm using dompdf to genearate a pdf ( $output = $dompdf->output();  ) and I need to attach it to phpmailer and mail it....

And I'm using sendgrid as mail services...

```
function sendEMailwithAttachment($mail_type, $mail_variable = array(), $subject, $from, $mailto, $username, $fileName, $filePath) { 

    $to = new SendGrid\Email($username, $mailto);
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", $message);
    $file = $filePath;
    $file_encoded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
    $attachment = new SendGrid\Attachment();
    $attachment->setContent($file_encoded);
    $attachment->setType("application/text");
    $attachment->setDisposition("attachment");
    $attachment->setFilename($fileName);

    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
    $mail->addAttachment($attachment);

}
```

How can I pass $output value in email

Is any way to pass $output as $filePath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your PDF file in the disk:

```
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('output.pdf', $output);
$fileName = 'output.pdf';  // Pass this variable to sendEMailwithAttachment function
```

Then pass the file path to the mail sender. After sending remove your pdf file from server.

Source: [how to save DOMPDF generated content to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720897/how-to-save-dompdf-generated-content-to-file)